# "Can I use either of them" or "Can I use both of them"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, sentence-choice, either-any

Let's say, in a question on this site, I am giving you two sentences which I think probably carry the same meaning and I want to ask you if I can use either of them interchangeably. I feel like if I say,

- "Can I use either of them"

or

- "Are/Is either of them okay",

it could be understood that I am asking if any of the two sentences I gave can be used while I am trying to ask if both of the sentences can be used. Do you think I can use the word, "either," in these questions, or do I have to use the word, "both," as in

- "Can I use both of them"

and

- "Are both of them usable"?

Comment: In your context, *Can I use **both**?* would be an "unusual" choice, because it strongly implies ***actually*** using both. As in - if you're asked whether you want tea or coffee, and you answer *Both*, by rights you should be given ***two*** drinks (one tea *and* one coffee). Whereas if you'd answered *Either*, you should be given just *one* (randomly selected at the behest of the asker) drink.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you are looking for an item in a shop and the shopkeeper shows you two that might fit your purpose.

To say **Can I use either of them (for the purpose)?**, asks whether both would fit the purpose but implies that you want just one of them.

**Can I use both of them (for the purpose)?** again asks whether both would fit the purpose but implies that you might want to purchase both, although it's ambiguous.

**Are they both usable?** simply asks whether both would fit the purpose.

When you ask **Is either usable**, you mean ** Is either one usable** so the singular **is** is required.

PS: The choice of verb after **neither** can be more complicated. See: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10304/which-is-correct-neither-is-or-neither-are

Comment: Thanks. As far I know, we can use "are" with "either of...".

Comment: https://editorsmanual.com/articles/either-is-or-either-are/#:~:text=The%20plural%20verb%20is%20common,these%2C%20either%20of%20them).&text=Informal%3A%20Either%20of%20these%20is,of%20these%20is%2Fare%20acceptable.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40477/the-usage-of-either-or

Answer (score 0):

"Can I use either of them?" is ambiguous between "Is each of them usable?" and "Is at least of them usable?"

"Can I use both of them?" is ambiguous between "Is each of them usable?" and "Can both of them be used together?"

Both of them will in most cases be inferred to mean "Is each of them usable?"

Eliminating ambiguity would require clunky wording, such as "Is it the case that I can use either one of them?"